# CORS blocking access to resource: How to fix in firebase cloud function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors, fetch-api

Yes, I have the dreaded CORS issue (or, at least it appears so)....and I have searched and tried a few solutions, to no avail...

I have no problems using firebase emulator and running my function locally, but when I deploy the function and try to send a POST request using fetch() on the local host client-side app, I get the following CORs browser console error (it won't even get to the server logs):

```
Access to fetch at 'https://us-central1-XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/deleteAsset' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

The FetchEvent for "https://us-central1-XXXXX.cloudfunctions.net/deleteAsset" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.

Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ firebase-auth-sw.js:77
firebase-auth-sw.js:77 
        
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at firebase-auth-sw.js:77
```

Here's my client side fetch request:

`UploadImage.vue`:

```
async deleteFile() {
      await fetch(
        'https://us-central1-XXXX.cloudfunctions.net/deleteAsset',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            public_id: this.imageSrc.public_id
          })
        }
      )
}
```

And then my firebase cloud function is like so:

`/deleteAsset.js`:

```
import cloudinary from 'cloudinary'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true })

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: functions.config().cloudinary.cloud_name,
  api_key: functions.config().cloudinary.api_key,
  api_secret: functions.config().cloudinary.api_secret,
  secure: true
})


export const deleteAsset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    try {
      functions.logger.log(req.body)
      cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(
        req.body.public_id,
        {
          invalidate: true
        },
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            res.status(500).send(error)
          }

          res.status(200).send(result)
        }
      )
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send('There was an error in deleteAsset function')
    }
  })
})
```

Anyone spot any issues or have any advice on how I can further troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Alright, so I fixed it....the CORS issue was due to the cloud function not having the right IAM permissions. I suspected it after looking at my dashboard (not shown on firebase console, had to go to Cloud Functions over at Google Cloud to see it!) and noticed that it was missing "Allow Unauthenticated". So, I manually deleted the function and redeployed. All good now!

[image]

Comment: As you were able to solve the initial issue, could you please mark the answer as accepted, it would really help to the community to identify it as a solution. Thanks

Comment: I would, but it didn't let me select my answer until a few days have passed.

Comment: Ok, don't worry wait a few day to see if they will let you to mark it as accepted.

Comment: You just deleted the function and re-deployed it and it worked? how did you add the "Allow unauthentication" label?

Comment: @OrNakash just delete functions and redeploy to apply changes you have made to IAM permissions

Comment: But does this open your function up to the public?

Answer (score 1):

In your cors's options, you're not setting localhost as a valid source.

Change the code from this

```
export const deleteAsset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, () => {
    try {
```

to this

```
export const deleteAsset = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  return cors({origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}, req, res, () => {
    try {
```

You should add all the origins you'll use, not only localhost. For furhter details on how to specify the allowed origins, take a look at the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Comment: thx! Investigating...

Comment: Unfortunately, still get the CORS issue. Do I need to remove `const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true }) ` from top?

Comment: Instead of removing, you can change the {origin:true} to {origin:'http://localhost:3000'}, it should be enough

Comment: still no luck. Thanks anyways! I'll try to deploy to remote server and see if that helps

Comment: Really weird. Same problem there.

Answer (score 1):

For the functions missing the **Allow unauthenticated** in the dashboard, select their checkboxes and click the **Permissions** button at the top. Click **Add Principal** and add the `allUsers` principal and grant the role `Cloud Functions Invoker`. [Link to docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#after_deployment)